# How to override variable lookup in R?

Tags: r, variables, ipc, scoping

Is it possible to redefine how R looks up variables?

Specifically, I have 2 R processes: client and server. I want to make the following extension to the server process' variable scoping rules: *if `x` cannot be found in any parent environment, instead query the client process for `x`*:

```
# i.e. when (in the server process) I write
x

# I actually mean:
if (exists("x")) {
    x
} else {
    getFromClient("x", port = 1234L)
}
```

Is this possible?

### Background

I'm doing a little [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) work at the moment, where client processes can issue commands to a server process to execute. However, commands inevitably operate on data (which resides with the client), and I am currently forced to manually hard-code-in every variable that needs to be exported from client to server.

Neither to I fancy the option of simply exporting the entire global environment of my client process, which may contain a lot of redundant data not useful for processing the command at hand.

Much better for the server just to query any variable from the client as and when the variable is required.

Comment: How about on the server doing something like `parent.env(.GlobalEnv) <- getFromClient(".GlobalEnv", port=1234)` or `attach(getFromClient(".GlobalEnv", ...))`?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde thanks, but the `.GlobalEnv` of my client process contains hundreds of MB to several GB of data! Only a small selection of variables is likely to be required when a command is issued to the server, so exporting all variables from the client (essentially what you are saying) is too inefficient a solution here. [Added this point to the question]

Comment: It's not clear to me that he is essentially saying that, especially for `.parent.env(.GlobalEnv) <-`. On the other hand, from `?parent.env`: "The replacement function parent.env<- is extremely dangerous as it can be used to destructively change environments in ways that violate assumptions made by the internal C code. It may be removed in the near future."

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like very lazy and dangerous and I'd advise against it.

The server code should know what variables it needs to get from the client, and should get those explicitly rather than waiting to try and trap an 'undefined variable' error.

What if the server code tries to get `x$foo` where `x` is a list on the server but doesn't have a `$foo` element? What about assignments to non-existent objects? What about typos?

There should only be one point in every program where a variable is born, and at that point you should either define it with a value or get its value from the server - there's no need to try and be lazy about it.

You risk writing code that only runs in your client-server environment and so is hard to test.